# Running spring-boot app from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a maven/spring-boot application with embedded-tomcat, that displays OK when run from command line: `java -jar ...`

When I import it into Eclipse, using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and then run the application main-class, however, it does not pickup the messages.properties file.

I get warning

```
ResourceBundle [messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name messages, locale xx_XX
```

and see these `??messageid??` in the browser.

How do I run it properly from eclipse?

What is the magic that spring-boot JarLoader does when starting from command-line?

Comment: Nothing magic I think. Is there a messages.properties? Is it in src/main/resources?

Comment: Yes, messages.properties is there. As I said, it works correctly when running from command-line: java -jar application.jar

Comment: If I copy messages.properties to messages_xx.properties or messages_xx_XX.properties before I build, it works. So seems to be a problem with fallback to default locale...

Comment: I found a related unresolved intellij-issue: 
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119230 
It says: "The key is to mimic the behavior of the @EnableAutoConfiguration annotation in the ide." 
So I guess Eclipse has the same issue?

Comment: That IDEA issue looks unrelated to me. Make sure your IDE is set to build projects automatically, and refresh the project before you run.

Comment: I have done all that, I can assure you :) But obviously, it is some problem in the frameworks functionality/config (not the build) since it does pick up messages_xx.properties (where xx_XX is your locale) but not the fallback, messages.properties, if the locale-specific are missing.